# How to add New item at TOP of listview, items are added from Json response

Tags: android, json, listview

- I know how to parse, set list-view adapter from json parsing
- But i want to know that when any new entry is added in list it should display at top of list rather than bottom
- I have fill up my list successfully and can manage notify changes

code for adapter :

```
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> postList;
// response is what i am getting from web-service :
     postList = parseContent.getPost(response);
      postAdapter = new PostAdapter(Fragment1.this,ctx, postList);
                        lvPost.setAdapter(fragAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add new item at index '0' of ArrayList.

I assume `postList` is a list containing items parsed from JSON. SO whenever you wanna add new item to it u can specify the index in Arraylist as below.

```
postList.add(0, "item");
```

Answer (score 1):

add item

```
postList.add(0, itemMap);
```

> and then call,

```
fragAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```